Decomposing an equation of order 3
I am trying to solve the following equation
$$(a+b) x^3 +(c+d) x^2 + a x + c =0, $$
where $a+b\neq 0$.
My attempt:
$$x^3 + \frac{c+d}{a+b} x^2 + \frac{a}{a+b}x +\frac{c}{a+b}=0.$$
we can assume that the above equation is decomposable as follows
$$(x+A)(x^2 + B x + C)=0$$
There we have the following system of equations
\begin{cases} 
A+B= \frac{c+d}{a+b}, \\
AB+C= \frac{a}{a+b}, \\
AC=\frac{b}{a+b}. 
\end{cases}
Eliminating B and C we can get
$$\frac{c}{(a+b)A}+A(\frac{c+d}{a+b}-A)= \frac{a}{a+b}. $$
I'm getting stuck at here and I don't know how to proceed...
Thanks for any help

See cubic equation

If we relabel $a = a_2, b = a_3 - a_1, c = a_0, d = a_2 - a_0$, we see that the equation is a general cubic, $a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 = 0$ (the condition $a + b \neq 0$ is just $a_3 \neq 0$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula
